# Getting ERROR in SQL with ORDER BY and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

When I am running the below SQL query in MySQL

```
select distinct city, length(city) from station order by length(city), order by city asc limit 1;
```

I'm getting ERROR as

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'order by city asc limit 1' at line 1
```

I am not able to understand where I am doing the mistake

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one ORDER BY is allowed, then comma delimit the column names like

```
order by length(city), city asc
```

Answer (score 3):

You have `order by` twice.  Presumably, you want:

```
select distinct city, length(city)
from station
order by length(city), city asc
limit 1;
```

That is, a single `order by` can have multiple keys.